# The fractal dimension of the Kolakoski sequence is $2-1/e$

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-function, fractals, conjectures

The Kolakoski sequence, which is defined as the

> infinite sequence of symbols {1,2} that is its own run-length encoding (Wikipedia),

has been suggested to be self-similar$^{1}$. The fractral dimension of a self-similar time-series is directly related to its Hurst exponent$^{2}$. I have estimated the Hurst exponent of the Kolakoski sequence for different sequence lengths, and found that the answer converges near $1 / e$ when the sequence length increases. This suggests that

> the fractral dimension of the Kolakoski sequence is $D=2-H = 2-1/e.$

Here is a small subset of the data

```
sequence length    hurst exponent
1e2                .1167
1e3                .1796
1e4                .2236
1e5                .2579
1e6                .3108
1e7                .3464
1e8                .3657
2e8                .3720
3e8                .3766
```

My question is: Can you find a proof for this conjecture? If yes, I would be interested to write a brief note about this to a mathematical journal.

References:

$^{1}$ https://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~brent/pd/Kolakoski-ACCMCC.pdf

$^{2}$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurst_exponent#Relation_to_Fractal_Dimension

Comment: That sounds curious, but is there any indication it has any practical implications?

Comment: @mathreadler Does it need to have a practical implication?  Isn't curiosity enough?

Comment: @XanderHenderson : No it doesn't *need* to. But I was curious.

Comment: You don’t seem to have nearly enough data to conjecture a Hurst exponent of $\frac1e$. The graph on page 31 of [these slides](https://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~brent/pd/Brent-NTDU17.pdf), which goes up to $7.6 · 10^{19}$, suggests a Hurst exponent of $\frac12$.